# Prove that $|f(z)| \leq 3|z|^2 $ for $1 \leq |z| \leq 2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is " If $f $ is analytic in the annulus $ 1 \leq |z| \leq 2 $ and $ |f(z)| \leq 3 $ on $ |z| = 1$ and $|f(z)| \leq 12 $ on $|z|=2$, prove that $|f(z)| \leq 3|z|^2 $ for $1 \leq |z| \leq 2$."

I have no idea how to start this, can anone help?

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(z)={f(z)\over z^2}$ is analytic in the annulus $1\leq |z|\leq 2$. Now estimate $|g(z)|$ on $|z|=1$ and on $|z|=2$, and use the maximum principle.